# Does the Quran have The sentence: "An Eye for An Eye"?

Tags: quran

Does the Quran have The sentence: "An Eye for An Eye" ?

Comment: What are you asking that even [the most basic Google search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=eye+for+an+eye+quran) couldn't already tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, it's in Surah al-Maidah 5:45:

> And We ordained for them therein a life for a life, an eye for an eye,
>   a nose for a nose, an ear for an ear, a tooth for a tooth, and for
>   wounds is legal retribution. But whoever gives
>   charity, it is an expiation for him. And whoever does not judge by
>   what Allah has revealed - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.